# I'm trying to add content into table on every click itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

Here are two ways on adding content into table on every button click

Example1

```
PdfPRow row1 = new PdfPRow(someArrayOfCells);
table.Rows.Add(row1);
```

Example2

```
 table.AddCell(Cell1);
 table.AddCell(Cell2);
 table.AddCell(Cell3);
 table.AddCell(Cell4);
 table.AddCell(Cell5);
 table.AddCell(Cell6);
```

Example 2 is doing the job for me, but example 1 not, can someone explain me why? I'm new in iTextSharp so if anyone could explain to me.

Comment: The `Rows` property is for internal use only. You shouldn't use it. It's not meant to work. You say that you're new in iTextSharp, but if that's so, why are you using an old version? iTextSharp was renamed to iText for .NET in 2016. You are using version 5 whereas the most recent version is iText 7. See the [official download page](https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/NET) for more info and read the [iText 7 jump-start tutorial](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial-net-version)

Comment: There is too little code to reproduce the issue. Actually you don't even tell us what the issue is.